# How do I place a marker relative to users current position?

Tags: android, maps

Hi I am new to Android and I am trying to write an app that displays a map and markers(representing people) relative to the  current location of the tablet,  like a HUD in a video game.  the location of a person is given in xy coordinates, so if a person is 4 ft in front and two ft to the left their coordinates would be (-2,4).

Right now I'm trying to place a marker on top of the current position to start with, but i am having some trouble. I have the map working and i have added the a custom marker and blue dot for current location but I cant get the marker to follow the blue dot

```
  private void setUpMap() {
    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
    TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
    numTxt.setText("Dave");
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    double dLatitude =mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    double dLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    markerLatLng = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);

    customMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(markerLatLng)
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Description")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker))));
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

here is the logcat

```
                java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.include(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdates.MainActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(MainActivity.java:398)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:808)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1768)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers aren't relative, they're fixed.  If you want it to track with the users location, you'll have to update it whenever the users location changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried running the code above inside my onLocationChanged method and it still crashes but ill keep trying

Comment: IF its a crash, post the stack trace.  That will get you more help, your initial question didn't mention any crashes.

Comment: I got it just had to take a break.